# Generate dynamic height horizontal listview nested in a vertical listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to generate a dynamic height HORIZONTAL listview that is nested inside a VERTICAL listview

I'm already in the point of printing my horiztonal listview, but the content of each card is cutted by the fixed height of the parent container of the horizontal list view, the dismiss animation is being cutted out as well because of the parent-container height of the horizontal list view

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Dismissible(
                  direction: DismissDirection.down,
                  key: Key('$index'),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      child: Text('${index}',
                        // here goes cutted long text
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ), 
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

link image, https://i.pinimg.com/564x/b7/f6/34/b7f6340dbb96212bc9c216e9bbc0d5da.jpg, stackoverflow doesn't let me post images yet :(

*Edit: What i look for is set every card height dynamically depending on the length of its child text

Answer (score 1):

To add dynamic height horizontal list-view inside vertical list you should switch to a **Row** inside a **SingleChildScrollview**:

**Example**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: [Text("SomeListText"), Text("SomeListText"), Text("SomeListText"), Text("SomeListText")],
              ),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for all the time!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your nested list view inside a container, can you try wrapping it with the Expanded widget?

Comment: hi friend, i replaced the container with an expanded and the root listview with a column (expanded can't be used inside listview) like this
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder( ...

but without success, now the containers fit the whole screen, what i want instead is every card of dynamic height depending on its content, thanks for the help